# Playing video at frame rates that are not multiples of the refresh rate.

Tags: opengl, video, frame-rate

I'm working on an application to stream video to OpenGL textures.  My first thought was to lock the rendering loop to 60hz, so to play a video at 30fps or 60fps I would update the texture on every other frame or every frame respectively.  How do computers play videos at other frame rates when monitors are at 60hz, or for that matter if a monitor is at 75 hz how do they play 30fps video?

Answer (score 2):

For most consumer devices, you get something like [3:2 pulldown](http://www.zerocut.com/tech/pulldown.html), which basically copies the source video frames unevenly. Specifically, in a 24 Hz video being shown on a 60 Hz display, the frames are alternately doubled and tripled. For your use case (video in OpenGL textures), this is likely the best way to do it, as it avoids tearing.

If you have enough compute ability to run actual resampling algorithms, you can convert any frame rate to any other frame rate. Your choice of algorithm defines how smooth the conversion looks, and different algorithms will work best in different scenarios.

Too much smoothness may cause things like the 120 Hz "soap opera" effect
[[1]](http://techcrunch.com/2009/08/12/help-key-why-hd-video-looks-weird/)
[[2]](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheCoconutEffect):

> We have been trained by growing up watching movies at 24 FPS to expect movies to have a certain look and feel to them that is an artifact of that particular frame rate.
> When these movies are [processed], the extra sharpness and clearness can make the movies look wrong to viewers, even though the video quality is actually closer to real.
>
> This is commonly called the Soap Opera Effect, because some feel it makes these expensive movies look like cheap shot-on-video soap operas (because the videotape format historically used on soap operas worked at 30 FPS).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you're dealing with a resampling problem. Your original data was sampled at 30Hz or 60Hz, and you've to resample it to another sample rate. The very same algorithms apply. Most of the time you'll find articles about audio signal resampling. Just think each pixel's color channel to be a individual waveform you want to resample.